# Using LAG function to produce entries for Customer

Tags: oracle, lag

I have the below setup which is just used to explain the problem

Here Car is the default vehicle bought if no other vehicle is bought

The logic is if there is a bulk payment then it should be split across the vehicles under Debit Customer

The actual transaction happens like the below

```
bought date              Bought   Credit_Acc  Debit Customer  paid_date
-----------              ------   ----------  --------------  ----------
 1-jan-2019              Bike      10k         0             03-Jan-2019
 2-jan-2019              cycle     20k         0             03-Jan-2019
 3-jan-2019              Car       30k        60k            03-Jan-2019
```

But the Customer wants the financial report to be like the below

```
 bought date             Bought   Credit_Acc  Debit Customer  paid_date
-----------              ------   ----------  --------------  ----------
 1-jan-2019              Bike      10k         10k             03-Jan-2019
 2-jan-2019              cycle     20k         20k             03-Jan-2019
 3-jan-2019              Car       30k         30k             03-Jan-2019
```

Also sometimes if he pays the only 15k which is recorded under Debit Customer
for 03-jan-2019 bought date then the report should be

```
 bought date             Bought   Credit_Acc  Debit Customer      paid_date
-----------              ------   ----------  --------------  ----------
 1-jan-2019              Bike      10k         10k                 03-Jan-2019        
 2-jan-2019              cycle     20k         5k                  03-Jan-2019    
 3-jan-2019              Car       30k         0(15k actual data)  03-Jan-2019
```

So after this 15k payment, another 15k payment is done on 04-Jan-2019 then 30k is recorded in Debit Customer base table but the report should show the below

```
 bought date             Bought   Credit_Acc  Debit Customer      paid_date
-----------              ------   ----------  --------------  ----------
 1-jan-2019              Bike      10k         10k                04-Jan-2019        
 2-jan-2019              cycle     20k         20k                04-Jan-2019
 3-jan-2019              Car       30k         0(30k actual data) 04-Jan-2019
```

Then after this payment, another 30k is made on 05-Jan-2019 then 60k is recorded under Debit Customer base table but the report should show the below

```
 bought date             Bought   Credit_Acc  Debit Customer        paid_date
-----------              ------   ----------  --------------  ----------     
 1-jan-2019              Bike      10k         10k                 05-Jan-2019        
 2-jan-2019              cycle     20k         20k                 05-Jan-2019
 3-jan-2019              Car       30k         30k(60k actual data)05-Jan-2019
```

TABLE STRUCTURE

```
VALUE DATE (bought date/paid date)  
ITEM (Bought)  
Debit_Entry (Debit Customer) 
Credit_Entry (Credit_Acc)
```

Comment: This isn't very clear at the moment. What data is actually in your table(s)? Where is the 15k recorded? What is the logic for the output? And what ordering are you applying here - is there a date you haven't shown, for instance?

Comment: @AlexPoole i have updated the information, the 15k is recorded under Debit Customer

Comment: the logic is if i make a bulk payment then it should be split across the different vechicles under debit customer

Comment: So are there (at least) two tables, one with purchases and one with payments? And what you've shown is supposed to be a point-int-time query of the current balances, with payments applied against purchases in date order? Again, show your actual table data (and structures), and show how that base data evolves as things are bought and payments made, and what your query (if that is what you need) should show at each stage.

Comment: Actually there is only one date which is Value date with tags used to define whether it is bought date or paid date which I can handle, My problem is handling the split amount in Debit Customer

Comment: i have added another two examples to give the complete cycle for one Customer,also handled one typo the total amount is not 50k it is 60k

Comment: i have added whatever information is requested to add,please let me know if any more information is required

Comment: You've still only shown the output you want (I think), not the actual table structure and data you're working from.

Comment: included the table structure

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's hard to tell from your question as the base table data still isn't shown, but it looks like you want something like:

```
select value_date, item, credit_entry, item_paid
from (
  select value_date, item, credit_entry, debit_entry,
    greatest(0, least(credit_entry, nvl(sum(debit_entry) over (), 0)
      - nvl(sum(credit_entry) over (order by value_date
          rows between unbounded preceding and 1 preceding), 0))) as item_paid
  from your_table
)
where item is not null;
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=323882396dc17bc8138269040cf62bd4)

For each row in the table, it sums up the total debit amount, and subtracts the total of the credit amounts up to (but not including) that row's. If that total payment is greater that the current row's credit then the credit value is used as-is; if it's negative (because the current item hasn't been paid off at all) then zero is used instead; otherwise the calculated value is used, which is the amount of that item's credit that has been paid off - after all previous items have been considered.